# How to make my function acceptable as MonteCarlo simulation input in R

Tags: r, simulation, montecarlo

I wrote the below `R` function to do the following task:

1. Simulate 10 time series data set from `ARIMA` model through `arima.sim()` function
2. Split the series into sub-series of possible `2s`, `3s`, `4s`, `5s`, `6s`, `7s`, `8s`, and `9s`.
3. For each size take a resample the blocks with replacement, for new series and obtain the best `ARIMA` model from the subseries from each block size through `auto.arima()` function.
4. Obtain for each subseries of each block sizes `RMSE`.

.

```
## Load packages and prepare multicore process
library(forecast)
library(future.apply)
plan(multisession)
library(parallel)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
n_cores <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(n_cores)
registerDoParallel(cores = detectCores())
## simulate ARIMA(1,0, 0)
#n=10; phi <- 0.6; order <- c(1, 0, 0)
bootstrap1 <- function(n, phi){
  ts <- arima.sim(n, model = list(ar=phi, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
  ########################################################
  ## create a vector of block sizes
  t <- length(ts)    # the length of the time series
  lb <- seq(n-2)+1   # vector of block sizes to be 1 < l < n (i.e to be between 1 and n exclusively)
  ########################################################
  ## This section create matrix to store block means
  BOOTSTRAP <- matrix(nrow = 1, ncol = length(lb))
  colnames(BOOTSTRAP) <-lb
  ########################################################
  ## This section use foreach function to do detail in the brace
  BOOTSTRAP <- foreach(b = 1:length(lb), .combine = 'cbind') %do%{
    l <- lb[b]# block size at each instance 
    m <- ceiling(t / l)                                 # number of blocks
    blk <- split(ts, rep(1:m, each=l, length.out = t))  # divides the series into blocks
    ######################################################
    res<-sample(blk, replace=T, 10)        # resamples the blocks
    res.unlist <- unlist(res, use.names = FALSE)   # unlist the bootstrap series
    train <- head(res.unlist, round(length(res.unlist) - 10)) # Train set
    test <- tail(res.unlist, length(res.unlist) - length(train)) # Test set
    nfuture <- forecast::forecast(train, model = forecast::auto.arima(train), lambda=0, biasadj=TRUE, h = length(test))$mean        # makes the `forecast of test set
    RMSE <- Metrics::rmse(test, nfuture)      # RETURN RMSE
    BOOTSTRAP[b] <- RMSE
  }
  BOOTSTRAPS <- matrix(BOOTSTRAP, nrow = 1, ncol = length(lb))
  colnames(BOOTSTRAPS) <- lb
  BOOTSTRAPS
  return(list(BOOTSTRAPS))
}
```

If the function is called as below:

```
bootstrap1(10, 0.6)
```

I get the following result:

```
##$BOOTSTRAPS
##            2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9
##[1,] 1.287224 2.264574 2.998069 2.349261 1.677791 1.183126 2.021157 1.357658
```

**My attempt to use `Monte Carlo` function to make my function run three(3) different and distinct times.**

```
param_list=list("n"=10, "phi"=0.6)
library(MonteCarlo)
MC_result<-MonteCarlo(func = bootstrap1, nrep=3, param_list = param_list)
```

I got the following `error message`:

> Error in MonteCarlo(func = bootstrap1, nrep = 3, param_list = param_list) :
> func has to return a list with named components. Each component has to be scalar.

**Please help me to get right what I did wrong either on my function or the `MonteCarlo()` function.**

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message, I would try replacing the end of your function with something like:

```r
names(BOOTSTRAPS) <- letters[1:10]
return(as.list(BOOTSTRAPS))
```

Then the resulting output is a named list with names `letters[1:10]`.